# is it possible to subclass an ant task?

Tags: java, ant

I wrote an ant task to run my project in NetBeans (I'm using a freeform java project).  Now I want to write a debug task.  The debug task is nearly identical to the run task except for a few added properties.  Can I subclass the run task and add in the extra properties?

Comment: Can you clearify your question? Are you talking about `target` or `task`? If you are talking about `task`s, then they are actually java classes so that you can `extends` them. If you are talking about `target`s, you'd better put your common xml code in a `macrodef`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since an Ant task implementation is a Java class, Ant tasks may be subclassed just like any other Java class. However, the usual method for testing tasks is to write both [JUnit](http://www.junit.org/) and [AntUnit](http://ant.apache.org/antlibs/antunit/) tests.

For examples, take a look at the Apache Ant source code under [tests](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/ant/core/trunk/src/tests/).